# Heroku Stormpath Unresponsive Registration Page

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, mean-stack, stormpath

I have followed the heroku guide [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stormpath) to configure stormpath authentication using express.js on my angular site. I am successfully able to navigate to the /login and /register pages at the root of my site. However when I try to register I always end up with no created user and my page looking like the image below.

[image]

Comment: Hi there!  Can you clarify which version of express-stormpath you are using?  Thanks!

Comment: I am using express-stormpath: 3.0.1 and I am using express: 4.13.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was actually that I was trying to add stormpath to a site that already was configured to be a single page app (angular). To do so you need to include the following

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, { 
   web: {
      spa:{
         enabled: true,
         view: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html')
      }
   }
}
```

Replace 'public' with you single page app's directory and replace 'index.html' accordingly

Answer was found in the express-stormpath documentation [here](https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath)

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with the environment variables, our documentation says that you should see these variables in your heroku applicatoin:

```
heroku config | grep STORMPATH
STORMPATH_API_KEY_ID:      5IFE9WD86423ZPOV8IEXAMPL
STORMPATH_APKI_KEY_SECRET: 0Fx+Ebqns9OWBO5lbHce6FAYTUtnSpYwcQ+DEXAMPLE
STORMPATH_URL:             https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/YoUrStOrMPaThApPlICAtiOnId
```

However, our express-stormpath library is expecting `STORMPATH_URL` to be `STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF`.  Can you try setting the `STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF` variable in your environment, to the HREF of your Stormpath Application?  Thanks!  P.S. I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) :)

Comment: Turns out the issue was that I was trying to add stormpath to a single page application (angular), that I already had. I will edit my question.

Comment: Oh awesome, I'm glad it's working now!  P.S. on StackOverflow, you can answer your own question - I'd suggest doing that here.  Happy coding!